# How to share view models between fragments using Google's GithubBrowserSample approach?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-2, android-architecture-components

I am very new using Android architecture components, so I decided to base my application using GithubBrowserSample to achieve many of my use cases. But i have the problem that i don´t know what is the correct way to share viewmodels between fragments with this approach.

I want to share the view model because i have a fragment with a viewpager with 2 fragments that need to observe data of the parent fragment view model

I used this before to achieve it, based on [google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    model = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this)[SharedViewModel::class.java]
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
}
```

but with the lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha03 seems to be deprecated

In GithubBrowserSample they have something like this to create an instance of a view model, but with this it seems to be a different instance every time

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

private val userViewModel: UserViewModel by viewModels {
    viewModelFactory
}
```

And i don't know where to pass the activity scope or if I should pass it.

I tried something like this

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    myViewModel = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
}
```

but im getting

```java
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModelFactory has not been initialized
```

I hope you can help me, i'm a little lost with this, sorry if my english it´s not that good

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`by viewModels()` provides a ViewModel that is scoped to the individual Fragment. There's a separate [`by activityViewModels()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#activityviewmodels) that scopes the ViewModel to your Activity.

However, the direct replacement for `ViewModelProviders.of(this)` is simply `ViewModelProvider(this)` - you aren't required to switch to `by viewModels()` or `by activityViewModels()` when using `lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha03`

Comment: Thanks, by activityViewModels () is what I was looking for since I'm now using the dagger view model injection approach, sorry if I didn't express my question correctly

Comment: I'm using Kodein, `by activityViewModels` instead of `by viewModels` worked for me! I looked forever how to use shared viewModels with Kodein, I didn't realize the solution i needed had nothing to do with Kodein! Thank you

Comment: @ianhanniballake would using `by activityViewModels` here when you have several shared ViewModels using a single Activity architecture result in any negative consequences?

Comment: @w3bshark - if you want something that is shared across your entire activity, that is exactly its use case and the reason it exists. There's also [`by navGraphViewModels()`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel) if you want something in between a single fragment and the whole activity.